# Creating an application using the google maps api that has a custom layer over top

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, layer

So, my question is somewhat of an odd request I think. I was an intermediate java programmer making android apps a couple years ago, but I quit for other things. Now I'm back with a new and (I think) somewhat bold idea and I need help.

I'm wanting to know if it is possible to utilize the google maps api to act as a base for another map that I layer over the top. Think of it as I'm changing the way the map looks and that's about it.

I'm wanting to create a mobile app that has a map with a new/different look than what the base and satellite views have for a set small area of the city. Think of it as something like taking any old image and slapping it over the top of the google map and still being able to navigate with it (obviously if it was a random picture you wouldn't be able to see where it was taking you, but in theory you could essentially create a new map).

Is this possible in both java and obj c?

Comment: Actually; I want to do something very similar : change the look of the different building blocks used by Google Maps.
I have not investigated it fully yet, but I fear it may not be possible.

Since I only want a map that allow to select a city, I will maybe create one map myself and simply map the gps coordinates on it.

Comment: So you mean you're going to essentially create a new map api from scratch? I'm really hoping it doesn't have to come to that :(

Comment: I am still investigating, no decisions taken. I only need a map to let the users select a city. So I don't need a big street resolution map, just a good resolution map of the world.
This is why it is tempting in my specific usecase to create a really beautiful world map, map an hundred of GPS coordinates on it; then interpolate the position of the user from the data sent by the GPS.

Using one of the libraries cited by @davehale23 is another option of course. advantage : probably much simpler :-)

Answer (score 0):

As far ask I know, you can't add your own tile layer to the Google Maps API for Android.  However, you can use [osmdroid](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/) and add your own tiles.  You could also use [mapsforge](http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/) for Android.  It comes with it's own tool for creating custom map tiles.